# Pagination calculation (Result Per page calculation after sorting)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination

I'm trying to develop pagination, and I'll need to figure out how to limit my result set by item offset. I managed to implement the start, end, and total page count in some way. However, when I sort the product data, the start, end, and total page count values remain the same.

eg.

> before sorted ->   Showing 1 to 10 of 60 ( 6 pages)
>
> after sorted ->  Showing 1 to 10 of 0 ( 0 pages)

```js
const totalProductCount = 60
const resultPerPage = 10
const currentPageNumber = 1
const totalPageCount = Math.round(totalProductCount / resultPerPage)
const from = parseInt((currentPageNumber - 1) * resultPerPage) + 1
const to = parseInt(currentPage * resultPerPage)

console.log(Showing {from} to {to} of {totalProductsCount} ({totalPageCount} Pages))

// Showing 1 to 10 of 60 ( 6 pages)
```

However, after the data is sorted, the totalProducts count falls to 0, and the result remains the same.

```js
const totalProductCount = 0
const resultPerPage = 10
const currentPageNumber = 1
const totalPageCount = Math.round(totalProductCount / resultPerPage)
const from = parseInt((currentPageNumber - 1) * resultPerPage) + 1
const to = parseInt(currentPage * resultPerPage)

console.log(Showing {from} to {to} of {totalProductsCount} ({totalPageCount} Pages))

// Showing 1 to 10 of 0 ( 0 pages) // still same
```